# Inserting a Matlab Float Array into postgresql float[] column

Tags: database, arrays, matlab, postgresql, jdbc

I am using JDBC to access a postgresql database through Matlab, and have gotten hung up when trying to insert an array of values that I would rather store as an array instead of individual values. The Matlab code that I'm using is as follows:

```
insertCommand = 'INSERT INTO neuron (classifier_id, threshold, weights, neuron_num) VALUES     (?,?,?,?)';
statementObject = dbhandle.prepareStatement(insertCommand);
statementObject.setObject(1,1);
statementObject.setObject(2,output_thresholds(1));
statementObject.setArray(3,dbHandle.createArrayOf('"float8"',outputnodes(1,:)));
statementObject.setObject(4,1);

statementObject.execute;
close(statementObject);
```

Everything functions properly except for the line dealing with Arrays. The object outputnodes is a <5x23> double matrix, so I'm attempting to put the first <1x23> into my table.

I've tried several different combinations of names and quotes for the `'"float8"'` part of the createArrayof call, but I always get this error:

```
??? Java exception occurred:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Unable to find server array type for provided name     "float8".
at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.createArrayOf(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:82)
at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.createArrayOf(Jdbc4Connection.java:19)

Error in ==> Databasetest at 22
statementObject.setArray(3,dbHandle.createArrayOf('"float8"',outputnodes(1,:)));
```

Comment: The problem ended up being with the qoutes. The java documentation uses double qoutes, but MATLAB doesn't recognize that. The correct line was:     statementObject.setArray(3,dbHandle.createArrayOf('float8',outputnodes(1,:))); I will post an answer as soon as the time limit is up.

Comment: Comment here when done; I'll upvote. Thanks for following up. For others reading, yes, `float8` is a valid type; its the internal alias for `double precision`. You can actually store your matrix directly in PostgreSQL as a 2-dimensional array, too.

Comment: Thanks Craig! I posted the correct answer below. I chose not to try to store the 2-d matrix this time due to the nature of the data, but it is really helpful to know that I can do that as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting confused with the documentation which all used double quotes, which Matlab doesn't allow, using only single quotes actually resolved this. The correct line was:

```
statementObject.setArray(3,dbHandle.createArrayOf('float8',outputnodes(1,:)));
```

instead of

```
 statementObject.setArray(3,dbHandle.createArrayOf('"float8"',outputnodes(1,:)));
```

I originally thought that the problem was with the alias that I was using for double precision was incorrect, but as Craig pointed out in the comment above this isn't the case.

Answer (score 5):

### Performance of JDBC connector for arrays

I'd like to note that in the case you have to export rather big volumes of data containing arrays JDBC may not be the best choice. Firstly, its performance degrades due to the overhead caused by a conversion of native Matlab arrays into `org.postgresql.jdbc.PgArray` objects. Secondly, this may lead to a shortage of Java heap memory (and simply increasing Java heap memory size may not be a panacea). Both these points can be seen on the following picture illustrating the performance of `datainsert` method from Matlab Database Toolbox (it works with PostgreSQL exactly through a direct JDBC connection):

[image: Performance for arrays]

The blue graph displays the performance of `batchParamExec` command from PgMex library (see https://pgmex.alliedtesting.com/#batchparamexec for details). The endpoint of the red graph corresponds
to a certain maximum data volume passed into the database by `datainsert` without any error.
A data volume greater than that maximum causes “out of Java heap memory” problem
(Java heap size is specified at the top of the figure).
For further details of experiments please see the following
[paper with full benchmarking results for data insertion](https://alliedtesting.github.io/pgmex-blog/2017/06/29/performance-comparison-of-postgresql-connectors-in-matlab-part-I/).

### Example reworked

As can be seen [PgMex](http://pgmex.alliedtesting.com/) based on libpq (the official C application programmer's interface to PostgreSQL) has greater performance and able to process volumes at least up to more than 2Gb.
Using this library your code can be rewritten as follows (we assume below that all the parameters marked by `<>` signs are properly filled, that the table `neuron` already exists in the database and have fields `classifier_id` of `int4`, `threshold` of `float8`, `weights` of `float8[]` and `neuron_num` of `int4` and, at last, that the variables `classfierIdVec`, `output_thresholds`, `outputnodes` and `neuronNumVec` are already defined and are numerical arrays of sizes shown in the comments in the code below; in the case the types of table fields are different you need to appropriately fix the last command of the code):

```
% Create the database connection
dbConn = com.allied.pgmex.pgmexec('connect',[...
    'host=<yourhost> dbname=<yourdb> port=<yourport> '...
    'user=<your_postgres_username> password=<your_postgres_password>']);

insertCommand = ['INSERT INTO neuron '...
    '(classifier_id, threshold, weights, neuron_num) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4)'];
SData = struct();
SData.classifier_id = classifierIdVec(:); % [nTuples x 1]
SData.threshold = output_thresholds(:); % [nTuples x 1]
SData.weights = outputnodes; % [nTuples x nWeights]
SData.neuron_num = neuronNumVec; % [nTuples x 1]
com.allied.pgmex.pgmexec('batchParamExec',dbConn,insertCommand,...
     '%int4 %float8 %float8[] %int4',SData);
```

It should be noted that `outputnodes` needs not to be cut along rows on separate arrays because the latter ones
are of the same length. In the case of arrays for different tuples having different sizes it is necessary to pass them
as a column cell array with each cell containing its own array for each tuple.

EDIT: Currently [PgMex](http://pgmex.alliedtesting.com/) has free academic licensing.

Comment: Note: Post author is employed by the firm producing the advertised product.